# App stuck on loading screen - no crash

Tags: ios

I'm here because I'm totally jammed on a problem, and I need some suggestions of where to look for an issue. I submitted an update to my iOS app, and when users try to update the app, the app no longer goes any further than the splash screen. They have to uninstall and reinstall the app for it to work properly.

I've testing the upgrade locally through xcode, and I tested it using TestFlight, and can't reproduce the behavior in either case. Does anyone have an idea what this could be?

**Edit**
I should also add, there is no crash. It just hangs there.

Comment: Did you try to build your application on the release mode?

Comment: Sound to me like an unhandled exception. If this problem happens only on your rolled out version (production version), I would start by looking in your app's initiate screen's code for places where you might be getting an exception without handling it, and surrounding it with `try` and `catch`. You wrote *"They have to uninstall and reinstall the app"* - this should alert you that it's something to do with data stored on the device.

Comment: @ridvankucuk ya - I tested the build in release mode via testflight, and tested the update from the app store to the testflight build, in release mode

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really a site for *please make a list for me of the hundreds/thousands/millions of things that could be going wrong with the code I can't show you with no information available* questions. This site is for *specific questions*, and there is nothing even remotely specific about *Does anybody have any idea why my app is stuck?*

Comment: @KenWhite I completely understand that. I know I've got a _really_ non specific issue, and I've been a good member of this community for several years. I'm unfortunately in this jam, and have _no idea_ what could be causing it, and was hoping someone might have an idea

Answer (score 1):

Did you use Local database in app, previously?
if yes then migration is required, if you make changes in Database.

i think it maybe issue.

Comment: I did make changes to the Core Data db, but tested the migration, and it's work properly

Comment: than i have no idea sorry

Comment: you can add crashlytics in your app, so it gives you line number where it crash

Comment: That's the kicker - I have crashlytics in there. There is no crash. It just hangs on the splash screen

Comment: its really headache, do you perform any task on appdelegate?

Comment: Nothing really changed in the app delegate in this build - I added Firebase, but everything else stayed the same. All the major processes are on the background thread

Comment: In my case i make changes in AppDelegate, in 80 % of cases it give me correct and crash free result, but in 20% cases it crashes, because i forgot to add some validation, and verification. please make sure..
maybe a fool answer by me